# Struggling to use two forms with same function based view, connecting it to specific profiles

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

First off, I have a model named Account which ties into Django's native User model thorough a one to one field. I'm building an admin panel, where the goal is to be able to edit registered accounts (users) information through forms on their backend profile page.

I have managed to create a view using two forms (form for changing the user model and a form for changing the account model), but since the instance is `request.user`, I'm only able to edit my own information on the different profiles. I'm not sure how to tie the pk for account into the code.

The ultimate goal is for example:
http://path/to/user/profile/1 - Able to edit account 1's information
http://path/to/user/profile/2 - Able to edit account 2's information

I have tried to add pk to the definition of test, but without luck.

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       path("test/<int:pk>", views.test, name="test"),
]
```

## views.py

```
def test(request, pk):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.account)

        if u_form.is_valid() and a_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            a_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account updated')
            return redirect('/cms/test/')
    else:
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(instance=request.user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(instance=request.user.account)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'a_form': a_form
    }

    return render(request, 'cms/test.html', context)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: There is something strange with your view: only in case of a POST you construct two forms (`u_form` and `a_form`), but in case of a GET, the control flow will move to the `if` statement, without defining the forms, hence a `NameError`.

Comment: Specifically, the `if.. is_valid` block should be indented one more level; the `else` underneath refers to the initial `if`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so the code by itself works fine, but not for its intended use, but if i I'm logged in as user1, and want to view user2's profile, all the information in the forms is prefilled with user1's details (since this is the account i'm logged into). What i want to do is view user2's details when i visit user2's profile, view user3's details when i visit user3's profile and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with "using two forms in the same function-based view". Please give your question a title that actually refers to your problem, which is that you want to edit the given user's details rather than the logged-in one.

The solution is simply to get the relevant user and pass it, rather than `request.user` and `request.user.account`, as the instance parameter to the forms:

```
def test(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=user.account)

        if u_form.is_valid() and a_form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(instance=user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(instance=user.account)
    ...
```